# How to make my activity transparent?

Tags: java, android

I am making a keyboard ( InputMethodService ), which needs to launch a dialog.

As I found out, a service can not launch a dialog. So I made a separate activity which is called from the service by

```
                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), dialog.class);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

and show a dialog. The problem is that this activity replaces the previous one, where the user was typing something.

What do you think would be the best way to make it "transparent" ( i.e. not to push away the previous activity ) and also what would be the best way for this activity to talk back to the service, saying that dialog option was picked.

Thanks! :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an `Activity` (not a `Dialog`), you can add a dialog theme in the `activity` section of your `AndroidManifest`:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

As for getting back what the user pressed, you should use [startActivityForResult(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: yep, thanks! "<activity android:name=".dialog" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />" this worked great in the manifest!

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT launch an activity from an IME.  This is a huge break in the IME flow -- the activity comes along and does an app switch from the current app, taking focus from it, and breaking your connection with its current editor.

Also there is no way to get a result back from it, because you can only use startActivityForResult() from an activity.

To show a Dialog in your IME, just use Dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD_DIALOG before showing the dialog.

Comment: are you sure? It gives me "09-01 20:09:28.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12857): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRoot$W@40510e38 -- permission denied for this window type". Had spend yesterday whole day trying to fight it without success, so decided to make it run from a new activity.

Comment: Whoops, you are right, that currently can only be used by the system.  What you can do instead is use TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG and set the window token (WindowManager.LayoutParams.token) to be the token if your IME window (retrieved with View.getWindowToken()).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please maybe specify how to set this "(WindowManager.LayoutParams.token) to be the token if your IME window (retrieved with View.getWindowToken())" ?

Comment: View.getWindowToken().  Retrieve WindowManager.LayoutParams with Window.getAttributes().  Put it in the token field there.  Put this back with Window.putAttributes().

Answer (score 0):

To resume in code what have been said, let me share some code for those who need to test the solution:

```
// 1. CREATE THE DIALOG
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light)
builder.setTitle("Title").setMessage("This is the message for the user. ")
val mDialog = builder.create()

// 2. SET THE IME WINDOW TOKEN ATTRIBUTE WITH THE TOKEN OF THE KEYBOARD VIEW 
mDialog.window?.attributes?.token = this.mKeyboardView.windowToken

// 3. SET THE TYPE OF THE DIALOG TO TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG
mDialog.window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG)

// 4. SHOW THE DIALOG 
mDialog.show()
```